# Struggling with Haskell syntax with if's and else's

Tags: if-statement, haskell, syntax

I'm struggling with the syntax of Haskell and am getting receiving "error: parse error on input ‘if’" when I try to compile my script with GHCI. The aim of my code is to return the minimum and maximum of an unordered list. It does this recursively by splitting the list in half and finding the minimum and maximum of each half. If the list has only one element it simply returns that that element is both the maximum and the minimum, if the list has two elements it does a simple comparison to find the minimum and maximum. Here is my code, the "splitlist" function was taken from an online resource:

```
splitlist :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitlist xs = splitAt ((length xs + 1) `div` 2) xs

minMax :: [Int] -> [Int]
minMax x
    if length x == 1 then 
        [x, x]
    else if length x == 2 then 
        if (head x > tail x) then 
            [tail x, head x]
        else 
            [head x, tail x]
    else 
        listOfLists = splitlist x
        list1 = listOfLists!!0
        list2 = listOfLists!!1
        minMax1 = minMax list1
        minMax2 = minMax list2
        if (minMax1!!0 < minMax2!!0) then 
            min = minMax1!!0
        else 
            min = minMax2!!0
        if (minMax!!1 > minMax2!!1) then 
            max = minMax1!!1
        else
            max = minMax2!!1
        [min, max]
```

I am also suspicious that I am not attempting to do this in a way that Haskell was meant for, I'm a beginner and still accidentally treat it like python quite a lot. Ideally if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong with my method and then show me a method more in line with Haskell's design principles I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Not a quick answer I'm afraid, but if you're new to Haskell then I seriously recommend [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters). Amongst so much else, this will teach you how to write idiomatic Haskell code, using higher-order functions - then you will see how to find the min and max of a list in just one line of code rather than having to do all these ugly if/else statements. (Although even doing it naively, there are much better options than this ugly divide-and-conquer. And needless to say, there are standard library functions to find the min and max of a list.)

Comment: You're missing the `=` between `minMax x` and the body of the function again.

Comment: FWIW splitting the list in half doesn't seem very useful for this purpose. The best you can do is a linear scan of the elements anyway, so why not just do it that way?

Comment: there is no assignment in Haskell. names can be defined to refer to values, with `let` or `where`.

Comment: As a thumb rule, you should avoid partial functions like `head,tail,!!` in your code, and use pattern matching instead which usually leads to much simpler code. `length xs == 1` is also an antipattern costing O(N) when an O(1) pattern match suffices and provides the head & tail for free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things in your function that isn't valid Haskell syntax. You are missing a `=`, and you are trying to declare variables in a way Haskell doesn't allow.

I tried to rearrange your code to be correct and here is what I got:

```
splitlist :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitlist xs = splitAt ((length xs + 1) `div` 2) xs

minMax :: [Int] -> [Int]
minMax x = if length x == 1 then 
              [head x, head x]
           else if length x == 2 then 
                    if (head x > (head $ tail x)) then 
                      [(head $ tail x), head x]
                    else 
                      [head x, (head $ tail x)]
                else [if (minMax1!!0 < minMax2!!0) then minMax1!!0 else minMax2!!0,
                      if (minMax1!!1 > minMax2!!1) then minMax1!!1 else minMax2!!1]
  where
        listOfLists = splitlist x
        list1 = fst listOfLists
        list2 = snd listOfLists
        minMax1 = minMax list1
        minMax2 = minMax list2
```

It looks like your algorithm works as expected! It was a little tricky because this isn't usually the way most people tend to write Haskell methods.

Here is a different implementation that might be useful for comparison:

```
minMax        :: [Int] -> [Int]
minMax []     = []
minMax (x:xs) = minMax' x x xs
  where
    minMax' a b []     = [a, b]
    minMax' a b (x:xs) = minMax' (min a x) (max b x) xs
```

Comment: I forgot to add: `tail` is a method that returns the list with the first element removed. It looks like you were trying to use it to return the last item in the list. Since the list will only have two elements in it, I replaced `tail` with `head $ tail` which should do what you want.

Comment: Or you could just use `last`, which does indeed give the last element of a list (but like all these functions, crashes your program if you give it an empty list)

Comment: In your different implementation, I would instead use `minMax' a b (x:xs) = minMax' (min a x) (max b x) xs` and remove the second `[x]` case. There is no need to consume two elements at each recursion. `minMax (x:xs) = minMax' x x xs` should also work similarly. Also, the OP should consider returning `Maybe (Int, Int)` instead -- returning `[Int]` feels wrong.

Comment: @chi Oh yeah, good point. `Maybe (Int, Int)` seems way more idiomatic. I wanted the method to match the Retsek specification, but I guess since he asked for a more Haskell way to do it, there is no reason to stick to `[Int]`

Comment: @chi Oh yeah, and that makes way more sense. I don't know why I was recursively taking two elements.

Comment: It's not a method; it's a function. Methods are in classes.